# Purpose of `#ifdef MODULE` around module_exit()?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am currently looking through the code of a "third-party" driver in an attempt to figure out/learn how it functions. I've had a look at sites such as [this one](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch16lev2sec1), so I sort of understand how the basic  premise works, but I don't understand the purpose of `#ifdef MODULE` here. Google isn't really much help, but I think the definition refers to a kernel module? (I am also completely new to this.)

```
module_init(os_driver_init);
#ifdef MODULE
module_exit(os_driver_cleanup);
#endif
```

My question is, what happens if I remove the `#ifdef` statement? Also, why/when would it be necessary to include the `#ifdef` statement?

Comment: Is there an alternative (lower down in the code) `module_exit(...)` line? It may be that alternative functions are called, and the `ifdef MODULE` controls this

Comment: Maybe `MODULE` is to be defined when driver is statically compiled in to kernel? http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re02.html

Comment: Can you link to this "third-party" driver code? The `#ifdef` you're showing shouldn't be there any more.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The permalink is [here](http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/view/en/67634126) and the direct download link (that may or may not work?) is [here](http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/llisapi.dll/csfetch/67634126/DK16xx_V2p6p0.zip?func=cslib.csFetch&nodeid=88192690). That's a compressed file, so the file I'm looking at is actually in V2.6.0\DK16xx_V2p6p0\linux-sw\host_linx\driver\linux\cp16xx_linux.c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Linux kernel, most drivers can be either statically linked (built-in) to the kernel image itself, or built as dynamically-loaded modules (`.ko` files).

The `MODULE` macro is defined for a C file when it is being compiled as part of a module, and undefined when it is being built directly into the kernel.

The code you're showing is only defining `os_driver_cleanup` as a module-exit function when it is being compiled as a module.  However, this construct is unnecessary in modern kernel code;  [`include/linux/init.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h?v=3.16#L286) defines `module_exit()` as a macro, whose implementation depends on `#ifdef MODULE`.

Basically, you should always provide an exit function, and leave off the `#ifdef` around `module_exit()`. You should also mark your exit function with `__exit`, which will properly control inclusion of the code for your in the modular/non-modular case.

Here's an example of proper init/exit code.

```
static int  __init foo_init(void)
{
    /* Register driver, etc. */
}

static void __exit foo_cleanup(void)
{
    /* Unregister driver, etc. */
}

module_init(foo_init);
module_exit(foo_cleanup);
```